# Where is $page['sidebar_second'] rendered? I want to edit the style of the <ul> listing of the recent comments

Tags: theming, blocks

The comments in the block `recent comments` is styled with an unordered list. I want the points of the list beginn exactly under the `N` of `New Comments`.

Google Chrome tells me that there is a `padding-left: 40px;` attribute:
[image: padding-left: 40px;]

I do not know from where i get this attribute. I looked in my themes css files but there is no attribut `padding-left: 40px;`

Here is the element lookup in Firefox: [image: New Comments]

I need to set the `padding-left` attribute to exactly `15px`. This is how it should look like:
[image: This is how it should look like with padding-left: 15px]

I'm using the mas Theme in markapot.

Can I define the style of the `ul` in the function `$page['sidebar_second']`? If so, where is the sidebar built? 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please note if it is only about identifying CSS rules responsible for a way something is displayed, then it is off-topic. After all, you would need to search your CSS files just the same way if your site would be created with Wordpress or any other CMS. Or from scratch. Just a hint: do you know [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?

Comment: @Mołot sorry for that. Where can I post a question like this? in stackoverflow? I've simply added a new class to my `.css` file and now it works the way I wanted it.

Comment: Yes, questions that are strictly about CSS, and just happens to occur in Drupal, but are not Drupal-specific, belongs to Stack Overflow, or [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (but read their help center first!). On the other hand, if you need to identify a Drupal hook that adds class you don't want, for example, or ask about classes provided with Drupal core, this is the place for it. This very question might be a gray area, as it does have a Drupal-centric answer (and no one voted it off-topic so far - I just pointed potential issue for your consideration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to look in how theme works in Drupal. However, as per your question, $page['sidebar_second'] is the variable that stores the region "sidebar_second".
This region doesn't have any specific styles and this goes for all the other regions as well. If a block is created in your system it needs a region to be displayed. So The blocks are always assigned to the desired regions.

If you want to style the block then you have to find the candidate files via [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) & [devel_themer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module and then in the theme directory have to create the file and style. Also if you are not wiling to do that then write a overriding css for your theme that will override the styles like,

```
.class-name {
   padding: 15px !important;
}
```

But I would recommend not to use !important unless its really needed.

Comment: Yeah, i defined a new class (`#block-comment-recent ul`) and added the attribute `padding-left: 15px;`. Now it works without any problems. Thanks for your help!